# create a new column which is a value_counts of another column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas datafram` `df` that contains a `column` say `x`, and I would like to create another column out of `x` which is a `value_count` of each item in `x`.

Here is my approach

```
x_counts= []

for item in df['x']:
    item_count = len(df[df['x']==item])
    x_counts.append(item_count)
    
df['x_count'] = x_counts
```

This works but this is far inefficient. I am looking for a more efficient way to handle this. Your approach and recommendations are highly appreciated

Comment: Check second answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for groupby function that you are trying to get the count of items in x
There are many other function driven methods but they may differ in different versions.
I suppose that you are looking to join the same elements and find their sum

```
df.loc[:,'x_count']=1 # This will make a new column of x_count to each row with value 1 in it 
aggregate_functions={"x_count":"sum"}
df=df.groupby(["x"],as_index=False,sort=False).aggregate(aggregate_functions) # as_index and sort functions will allow you to choose x separately otherwise it would conside the x column as index column
```

Hope it heps.

Comment: Why `sum` with `1` column? In my opinion overcomplicated here

Comment: Check dupe for better solution, second answer.

Comment: It is also wrong, OP need `transform`

Comment: Yes I know that, I have tried searching over S/O when I was going through that issue nothing helped so I had to comeup with this, it's not recommended but can be helpful for someone new to build an understanding for groupby function

Comment: groupby function dos not fill in the exact number of rows. its  still doing value_counts and therefor not filling the rows